Application Fundamental Theorem of calculus - Replacing a function with its integrals
I was going through the solution of one of the questions asked on this platform.
Question link
I was able to follow the accepted answer until the last step where @Aryabhata substitutes
$$ g(t) = g(0) + \int_0^t g'(x) dx $$
I'm aware of  fundamental theorem calculus where we define the indefinite integral to be  $g(t):=\int_0^t g'(x) dx $
I'm not exactly sure why g(t) was substituted as $ g(0) + \int_0^t g'(x) dx$ instead of $\int_0^t g'(x) dx $? and if the Fundamental theorem of calculus inspired this substitution? If yes, Are there any different forms or corollaries associated with this theorem?

Fundamental theorem of calculus says: $\int_a^t g'(t)\ dt = g(t) - g(a).$  In this example, we have $a=0.$

If you haven't learned the relation mentioned in the comment above, here is a derivation: Any two differentiable functions on an interval, whose derivatives agree, only differs by addition of a constant term. Since you know that both $$g(x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\int_{0}^{x}g'(t),\mathrm{d}t$$ have the same derivative, namely $g'(x)$, you also know that $$g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g'(t),\mathrm{d}t+\mathsf{C}$$ for some constant $\mathsf{C}$. Then you can determine its value by plugging $x=0$.

Actually the fundamental theorem doesn't state that $g(t)= \int_0^t g'(x)dx$.  It states that if $h(t)=\int_0^t g'(x)dx$ then $h'(t)=g'(t)$.  As a corollary we know $g(t)=h(t)+C$ for some constant.  Alternatively $\int_0^t g'(x) = g(t)-g(0)$ (which is also, by the way, equal to $h(t)-h(0)$.)  Putting that together:  If $\int_0^t g'(x)dx=g(t)-g(0)$ simple arithmetic tells us that $g(t)= g(o) + \int_0^t g'(x)dx$.  You can read about formal statements and corollaries here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements

If $g$ is an antiderivative of $g'$, then
$$ \int_a^b g'(t) dt = g(b) - g(a).$$
Here we apply this with $a = 0$ and $b = x$, getting
$$ g(x) = g(0) + \int_0^x g'(t) dt.$$
It is easy to confuse this with one of the fundamental theorems of calculus, which says that if $f$ is an integrable function and we define
$$ F(x) := \int_0^x f(t) dt, $$
then $F'(x) = f(t)$. Observe that defining $F_1$ as
$$ F_1(x) := \int_1^x f(t) dt$$
gives another function differentiating to $f$, i.e. $F_1'(x) = f(x)$. If we care about exactly what the derivative/antiderivative relationship is, we might need to specify the constant of integration.

Wouldn't $ F_1(x) & F(x)$ be the same function? I mean what role does the lower limit play in the definition of anti-derivative?

@Ark No. Take a concrete example, like $f(x) = 1$. Then $F(x) = x$ while $F_1(x) = x - 1$, which are clearly different functions.
